# Listview Flicker and Out Of Memory issues

Tags: vb.net

In my application i am having memory issues adding tot he listview, once it's running you can't look at the listview contents becuase it flcikers and slows down, once xx,xxx items are added and you try to view the listview in the tabcontrol i immediately get an out of memory error.

I have closed everything i can:

```
                doc = Nothing
                allHtml = Nothing
                tables_1 = Nothing
                tables_2 = Nothing
                GC.Collect()
```

Which does help on the initial insertion, it's when i view the listview the crash occurs.

thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Simple ways to avoid the flicker is ListView.Begin/EndUpdate() and [enabling double-buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.doublebuffered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  But everything has a upper limit, the one you are exercise is *well* beyond the user's patience with having to claw through hundreds of thousands of items.  Have a look-see how Google presents that many query hits.

Comment: Thanks Hans :) working great :)